# Draw lines in WPF like in WinForms

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, filter

How can I draw Lines in WPF so that the result looks like `Winforms` result?

- I've got this image: `PictureBox.BackgroundImage`

  [image]
- I reverse it to this:

  [image]
- What I get: `PictureBox` screenshot

  [image]
- Code:

  > brush := `TextureBrush` from reversed bitmap
  >   size := 300
  >   barWidth := 25
  >   barSpacing := 5
  >   Result gets `PictureBox.Image`

  ```
  public Bitmap CreateSpectrumLine(Brush brush, int size, int barWidth, int barSpacing)
  {
      using (var pen = new Pen(brush, (float)barWidth))
      {
          var b = new Bitmap(size, size);
          using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(b))
          {
              g.Clear(Color.Transparent);
              g.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.None;
              int h = size;
              PointData[] points = CalculatePoints(size);

              for (int i = 0; i < points.Length; i++)
              {
                  PointData p = points[i];
                  int barIndex = p.PointIndex;
                  float x = (float)((barWidth + barSpacing) * barIndex + barWidth / 2);

                  var p1 = new PointF(x, h + 1);
                  var p2 = new PointF(x, h - (float)p.Value + 1);

                  g.DrawLine(pen, p1, p2);
              }
          }
          return b;
      }
  }

  struct PointData
  {
      public int PointIndex;
      public double Value;
  }
  ```

How can I achieve the same result using `WPF` components/commands (resulting in an `BitmapSource`)?

Comment: Hard to answer without knowing what CalculatePoints does.  If your x values are correct, and y values are not, there could be an issue with your algorithm above.  For `p1` and `p2`, why are you varying y?  Shouldn't this always go from `0` to `size-1`?  The `h` variable is not needed, and you could use `size` instead to make code more readable. Since all your values are `int`, you could change `x` to `int`, not cast `float`, and use `Point` instead of `PointF`.